# Facebook : how to get number of friends?

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to be able to retrieve some people number of friends on Facebook. However, I got some issue to achieve this goal. I tried two different ways:

**1. With FQL:**

I tried [following query](http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=SELECT%20username,%20friend_count%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20username=%22jonathan.petitcolas%22):

```
SELECT username, friend_count
FROM user
WHERE username = jonathan.petitcolas
```

But, as you can see, the friend_count property is always null. On my public profile, and also on other profiles.

**2. With Facebook PHP SDK**

Then, I installed the Facebook PHP SDK, created an application, and did the following:

```
$facebook = new \Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'XXX',
    'secret' => 'XXX'
));

$friends = $facebook->api('/jonathan.petitcolas/friends');
```

Then I got the following exception:

> [FacebookApiException]
>   (#604) Can't lookup all friends of 676944843. Can only lookup for the
>   logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your
>   app.

Indeed, I am logged in with another user.

So, is it possible to retrieve number of friends of a public profile on Facebook? Is so, how to do this?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried following query:

```
SELECT username, friend_count
FROM user
WHERE username = jonathan.petitcolas
```

> But, as you can see, the friend_count property is always null. On my public profile, and also on other profiles.

Nope, it’s not always null. If I do that query with my own user name (and correcting the syntax error in your query), I get back the correct number of friends. Only if I authenticated that app making the query, of course.

> So, is it possible to retrieve number of friends of a public profile on Facebook?

Nope.

That says enough already:

> “Can *only* lookup for the logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your app.”

Comment: Well... OK. Seems clear now. We can not retrieve friend number of a lambda public profile. Thanks.